# Unite Gallery images appearing twice

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've encountered an issue with the unite gallery library where by I have multiple gallery's on the same page. Upon page load, I am iterating over each on and initializing the unite gallery on it. All works fine until you take a look at it on Chrome Desktop and see some of the images are repeating themselves at the bottom of the page. You can see what I mean here: https://www.brothers.deence-preview.com/previous-domestic-flooring-work/

Here is the code I use to initialize each gallery:

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var galleryCount = $('#gallery-count').val();
    for (var i = 1; i < galleryCount; i++) {
      $('#project-images-' + i).unitegallery({
        gallery_theme: "compact",
        slider_enable_zoom_panel: false,
        gallery_images_preload_type: "minimal",
        gallery_mousewheel_role: "none"
      });
    }
    $(".projects-loading").hide();
  }, 250);
});
```

Although as this only seem to be an issue with Chrome, im not sure if this is the problem.
Any direction would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: I have check with the link but it is working, it's not repeating the image. Can you please take a look once?

Comment: Sure, here is an example of what it looks like on my screen: https://imgur.com/a/uXRzE0g As you can see circled in red, some of the images from further up the page have been duplicated further down. Just to check, are you looking at this on a desktop version of Google chrome as that is the only browser I have been able to re-create it on. Cheers!